# Android: layout_width and height crop my image

Tags: android, layout, imagebutton

i have this little layout i defined to inserted in every page of my app:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/button"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
    android:background="@null"
    android:src="@drawable/sa_info"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"/>
```

i've sa_info.png that is 118x118  but i want it to look much smaller on the screen. if i try to set width and height of the imagebutton to the desired size (lets say 48dp) the resulting image when i run the app is cropped to the center:
[image: original image]
[image: cropped image]

so the only way i have to get the desired result is scale the image itself to the desired resolution. 
what i'm doing wrong, is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try adding

**android:scaleType="fitCenter"** -> http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.ScaleType.html

**android:adjustViewBounds="true"** -> Set this to true if you want the ImageView to adjust its bounds to preserve the aspect ratio of its drawable.